# How to find the Keda ScaledJobs that are configured on my Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, keda

If I understood well, they are not visible in the cluster's dashboard (default Kubernetes dashboard).
How can I list them, and eventually modify them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have Keda on the Kubernetes cluster, you can simply use `kubectl` to list the ScaledJobs and modify them.

- To list the ScaledJobs:
  `kubectl get ScaledJob`
- Them to modify one of them:
  `kubectl edit ScaledJob {ScaledJobName}`